# Docker cp command not allowed

Tags: docker

I'm trying to copy a file from a container to my host windows machine with this command

```
docker cp my_container:/folder c:\anotherfolder
```

the docker console returns

```
copying between containers is not supported
```

Why?

```
 Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Fri May  5 15:36:11 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 21:43:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think it's because docker thinks `c` is container name. You can use relative path rather than absolute path.

So if you are in `C:/` you can just:

```
docker cp my_container:/folder anotherfolder
```

Also notice that there are few differences between running commands in window's `cmd` and in `git bash`.

**1.  You are using git bash:**

Or escape in `git bash` console on windows:

```
WlaDo@DESKTOP-RBBRJOD MINGW64 ~
$ docker cp eb19fc21889c:/data c:\test
copying between containers is not supported <--- we got this error which points to implementation for which I added link below

WlaDo@DESKTOP-RBBRJOD MINGW64 ~
$ docker cp eb19fc21889c:/data c:\\test
<--- no errors here -->

WlaDo@DESKTOP-RBBRJOD MINGW64 ~
$ ls c:\\test
<--- data from container -->
```

**2.  You are using windows `cmd`**

From windows `cmd` the approach you have should work:

```
C:\Users\WlaDo>docker cp eb19fc21889c:/data c:\test
<--- no errors here -->

C:\Users\WlaDo> dir  c:\test
<--- data from container -->
```

Copying between containers [is not implemented](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/cli/command/container/cp.go#L100) and throws the error.

For more info check documentation about [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#extended-description)

> A colon (:) is used as a delimiter between CONTAINER and its path. You
>   can also use : when specifying paths to a SRC_PATH or DEST_PATH on a
>   local machine, for example file:name.txt. If you use a : in a local
>   machine path, you must be explicit with a relative or absolute path,
>   for example:
>
> `/path/to/file:name.txt` or `./file:name.txt`

Answer (score 6):

As the other answer stated, it's because it thinks the `c:` is a container name. You can solve this by wrapping the path in quotes like `docker cp my_container:/folder "c:\anotherfolder"`

Answer (score 0):

A working path spec in mingw32 (git bash):

```
/$(pwd)/projects/acme
```

Note the `/` prefix!